# Check All input text fields in form empty or not on Submission, Ignore if at least one text field is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp, validation

Here is the situation

I have a form with many input fields in my JSP page. The number of input text fields are unknown as it is based on the previous action class.

When the form is submitting, I want to check all input text fields are empty or not. If all are empty, then it should not submit. Otherwise( in any case. ie, at least one text field must be filled), then form should submit.

**The JQuery I have tried:**

```
$('#dataFieldMapping').submit(function() {
    if ($('input:text').is(":empty")) {
        alert("Empty!");
        preventDefault();
     }
});
```

(*dataFieldMapping* is the id of form). When I click on submit, it alerts with "Empty!" always, even if all text fields are filled.

**NB**: My submit button is outside of form. So I was using

```
$('#dataFieldMapping').submit();
```

without validating. But I want to validate the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H4t98/)

```
$('#dataFieldMapping').submit(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).find('input:text').filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value) != ""
    }).length) {
        alert("Empty!");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling preventDefault on event object, you need to call `preventDefault` on event object. The way you are trying to check that all fields are empty wont give you correct result as it will checks children not value.

> :empty Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes), [reference](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

```
$('#dataFieldMapping').submit(function(event) {
    lst = $('input:text').filter(function(){
         this.value != "";
     });
    if(lst.length)
    {
       alert("Empty!");
       preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what OP wants, no?  << in any case. ie, at least one text field must be filled), then form should submit.>>  Here if at least one input is empty, you don't submit the form. BTW, you are returning anything from filter() method

Comment: My form gets submitted in all cases. Not even alerting

Comment: Yes. It is the form ID

Comment: @ShijuKBabu but have you tested my answer or what???  If doesn't work let me know...

Comment: after that only i commented here

Comment: @ShijuKBabu So you discard all other answer?  Really?!

Comment: @roasted I got another answer also which looked same at first. But I got it correct and have accepted

Comment: forgot the `return` statement in `.filter`